# First images inside a row smaller than other ones html/css

Tags: html, css

Hi I am doing an Exercise for the Academy and I'm making a blog but the first images are smaller than they should be, please help

Here the code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Image Gallery</h1>
            </div>
            <hr class="style-four">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- This Row is the one that is smaller -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
                    </div>
                </div>

             <!-- This row is ok-->
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is an Image of my result:
[image: Image here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but try this: you are missing the ending **`</div`>** tag for your first row. As well as the same ending tag for the container class.

I added both, it should be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Image Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <hr class="style-four">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- This Row is the one that is smaller -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- added the missing end tag -->
    <!-- This row is ok-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the first `row` div, that's why this sizing issue occur.
you can find updated HTML code below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Image Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <hr class="style-four">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- This Row is the one that is smaller -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- This row is ok-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469173479606-ada03df615ac?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```